# Behavior of Lorenz Attractor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to understand the behavior of the Lorenz attractor. I understand that it is very sensitive to initial conditions but I don't understand **WHAT** I'm looking at. So here are two lorenz attractor figures from matlab:
[image]
[image]

The only difference between both of them is the initial condition of $x_2$ changes from 0 to -3. But I don't understand what is going on or how to describe it.

In very amateuristic terms, I can say that the lorenz attract is showing heavy circulation on the right lobe of the first figure and low circulation in the left lobe but in the 2nd figure it's just the opposite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking at is the trajectory of a particle that is moving in accordance with a fairly simple collection of equations. If the particle starts at $(-1,0,1)$, it traces out the curve in the first diagram; if it starts at $(-1,3,1)$, it traces out the second.

These two diagrams don't really illustrate "sensitive dependence on initial conditions". What that means is that even if two particles start out very near each other, say, one at $(-1,0,1)$ and the other at $(-1,.0001,1)$, they will only stay close for a little while, and then they will move very far apart (while staying on the attractor).

To see sensitive dependence, try http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FYE4JKAXSfY or http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=97ryBYOTQ0o

What the two diagrams do show is how complex the individuals trajectories are.

Answer (score 0):

The terms x,y,z (x1,x2,x3 in your case) are the coefficients of the Fourier series expansion of a mathematical model of fluid convection. The magnitude of these terms describes how the system evolves in time. Each point in phase space corresponds to a particular system with a particular convection speed and temperature gradient. You can easily find a derivation on this [course website](http://www.cmp.caltech.edu/~mcc/Chaos_Course/Lesson1/Introduction.html) or by doing a Google search.

Bruce Stewart provides a wonderful intuitive explanation of what the Lorenz system means in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YS_xtBMUrJg).